# Suggestion of topics in General Topology for PhD interview

Tags: soft-question, research, career-development

I got shortlisted for PhD admission .I've to prepare a presentation as a part of my interview.My research interest is General Topology. I've studied Munkre's topology upto Chapter 8.
Please suggest me some topic from Munkre's which can be presented as a presentation in interview within 8 minutes.

Thank you

Comment: Borsuk-Ulam theorem:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yuVqxCSsE7c

Comment: Were I at your interview I would want to know why you found your topic particularly interesting and appropriate. That would be more important than what the topic actually was. It's not the kind of thing I'd want you to have found out by asking here ...

Comment: @DavidG.Stork:thanks for your suggestion,but it comes under Algebraic topology

Comment: I think the interests of the department would be a major consideration, along with your specific interests, neither of which you've provided. There can be a big difference between set theoretic topology, continuum theory, generalized topological notions, categorical topology, compactification theory, infinite dimensional topology, generalized metric/uniform spaces, dimension theory, hyperspace theory, etc.

Comment: @EthanBolker:I've learned  topology all by myself with the help of internet.Thinking over your valuable advice I came to the conclusion,Since in  General topology we try to explore the conditions which can make the given spaces Metrizable(if i'm not wrong).So, I can give a glimpse of the theorems which talks about metrizability...what you say??

Comment: *Since in General topology we try to explore the conditions which can make the given spaces Metrizable* --- If you think that's what general topology is mostly about, then I recommend looking at the table of contents to [**Encyclopedia of General Topology**](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0444503552) edited by Hart/Nagata/Vaughan (2004).

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro:Thanks,I'll definitely go through this

Comment: It's also relevant whether this is a U.S. university in which you don't need a specific research plan in advance (roughly the first 2 years are spent taking courses in many different areas and passing the Ph.D. qualifying exams) as compared to some European universities in which it is often the case that you're expected to have a specific supervisor in mind and begin working on a research topic immediately.